fetch with the whole url work but not when i'm setting proxy, why ? should i create constant instead?
If I try to get datas from my local server with the whole url, it works:
fetch("http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000/members")
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) => {
            console.log(myJson);
        })

output:
{"members": ["Members1", "Member2", "Member3"]}

but if I'm setting a proxy in my package.json, it doesn't:
"proxy":"http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000/",

fetch("/members")
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) => {
            console.log(myJson);
        })

output:
TypeError: Network request failed

I have read somewhere that it's not possible to set up a proxy in react native ?
So does the good way to do is to set a constant that I call each time?
For add some details:
I use expo and start it like this: npx expo start --dev-client --tunnel

what do you think setting a proxy in package.json achieves?

The point of a proxy is not to provide a way to specify a base URL path, which is what you appear to be trying to use it for here. A proxy is a machine that makes a request to an endpoint on your behalf, instead of you making the request directly.

@Jaromada_X A gateway to the server?

The proxy needs to know the server you want it to connect to on your behalf.

When you omit the server name in a URL, the server name of the current page is used. The proxy doesn't change this.

@Barmar Hoo okay, i was not in the good direction so. Thank you.
